# Is it possible to track Table Addition on database through Change Data Capture(CDC) or similar technique?

Tags: sql-server, database, migration, database-migration, cdc

I am in the process of migrating whole production database from MS SQL to My SQL servers. I am employing CDC and SQL Trace to do the same. Log Sequences Numbers(LSN) in CDC enabled me to carry out operations without redundancy. But CDC doesn't provide much scope for DDL operations.

I tried to resolve issues by reading changes from cdc.ddl_history table and then employing necessary action (For e.g. in case of column addition, I started 2nd Capture instance and Synced it with the first one). Now, this was easy as I still have LSN values from cdc.ddl_history table. But this doesn't accommodate for Table addition into the database as cdc needs to be enabled on each table.

Currently I have a solution using SQL Trace in which I figure out by running a routine service of table creation and then enabling CDC on it but I think this will lead to loss of data as CDC is not real time and completely based on log transaction record.

What's the best possible way to tackle this issue leading to minimum/no loss of data?

Comment: If you are migrating the database from sql server to mysql why are you trying to capture ddl changes? Wouldn't you migrate the entire database and be done with it? And not sure how CDC helps you migrate from one database to another.

Comment: The source server is dynamic and changes done to MS SQL server during the process should be reflected back in My SQL server. Migration might be wrong word, its more of an ETL task.

Comment: Ahh that makes WAY more sense to me now. I follow what you mean.

Comment: Have you looked at using ddl triggers? That would let you see all ddl changes.